# CodeIgniter Redirect issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, port

I am testing a server on http://example.com:8080, my CI app is here http://example.com:8080/app/

I have a port forward from 8080 (external) to 80 (internal)

My config.php looks like this:

```
...
$config['base_url'] = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/app';
...
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

How should look the .htaccess file in order to get the site working. Also I have used this https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html with success on port 80, but cant get it work on 8080. If I leave the index.php in the url then everything works well also on port 8080.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this .taccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Its not clear your question why your redirect not working. Hope this help you. Always put what you have tried so far so everyone can understand better.

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found the issue... The rewrite module was not enabled, so I have enabled and everything works well.